# SQL server - Split and sum of a single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table cell of type nvarchar(max) that typically looks like this:
A03 B32 Y660 P02

e.g. a letter followed by a number, separated by spaces. What I want to do is get a sum of all those numbers in a SQL procedure. Something rather simple in other languages, but I am fairly new to SQL and besides it seems to me like a rather clumsy language to play around with strings.
Aaanyway, I imagine it would go like this:

1) Create a temporary table and fill it using a split function

2) Strip the first character of every cell

3) Convert the data to int

4) Update target table.column set to sum of said temporary table.

So I got as far as this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SumCell] @delimited nvarchar(max), @row int
AS
BEGIN
declare @t table(data nvarchar(max))

declare @xml xml 
set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,' ','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' 

insert into @t(data) 
select  
    r.value('.','varchar(5)') as item 
from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r) 

UPDATE TargetTable
SET TargetCell = SUM(@t.data) WHERE id = @row
END
```

Obviously, the first char stripping and conversion to int part is missing and on top of that, I get a "must declare the scalar variable @t" error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very clear so assuming your text is in a single cell like **A3 B32 Y660 P20** following snippet can be used to get the sum.

```
DECLARE @Cell NVARCHAR(400), @Sum INT, @CharIndex INT

SELECT @Cell = 'A3 B32 Y660 P20',@Sum=0

WHILE (LEN(LTRIM(@Cell))>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @CharIndex =  CHARINDEX(' ',@Cell,0)

    SELECT @Sum = @Sum + 
       SUBSTRING(@Cell,2,CASE WHEN @CharIndex>2 THEN @CharIndex-2 ELSE LEN(@Cell)-1 END )

    SELECT @Cell = SUBSTRING(@Cell,@CharIndex+1,LEN(@Cell))

    IF NOT (@CharIndex >0) BREAK;
END
--@Sum has the total of cell numbers
SELECT @Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you really want to be able to find the sum of values in your delimited list for a full selection of a table.  Therefore, I believe the most complicated part of your question is to split the values.  The method I tend to use requires a numbers table, So I'll start with that:

```
--If you really want to use a temporary numbers table don't use this method!
create table #numbers(
  Number int identity(1,1) primary key
)
declare @counter int
set @counter = 1
while @counter<=10000
 begin
    insert into #numbers default values
    set @counter = @counter + 1
 end
```

I'll also create some test data

```
create table #data(
  id int identity(1,1),
  cell nvarchar(max)
)
insert into #data(cell) values('A03 B32 Y660 P02')
insert into #data(cell) values('Y72 A12 P220 B42')
```

Then, I'd put the split functionality into a CTE to keep things clean:

```
;with split as (
    select d.id,
        [valOrder] = row_number() over(partition by d.cell order by n.Number),
        [fullVal] = substring(d.cell, n.Number, charindex(' ',d.cell+' ',n.Number) - n.Number),
        [char] = substring(d.cell, n.Number, 1),
        [numStr] = substring(d.cell, n.Number+1, charindex(' ',d.cell+' ',n.Number) - n.Number)
    from #data d
        join #numbers n on substring(' '+d.cell, n.Number, 1) = ' '
    where n.Number <= len(d.cell)+1
)
select id, sum(cast(numStr as int))
from split
group by id
```